# Overly large .exe file when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, executable, pyinstaller

I've searched a little bit about this problem where people complained about the executable file size being 30mb ~ 100mb, but for some reason mine is 300mb. I may be wrong, but I don't think this is normal. I tried using other alternatives like cx_Freeze, but I get the same result. Here's my includes in my project :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from pyplot import functions as plot
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

pyplot is another python file for my project which include :

```
from numpy import power, cbrt, sin, cos, arange
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches as pts
from scipy import integrate as intg
```

I use this command to create my executable :

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed montecarlo.py
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: PyQt5, numpy, scipy, mathplotlib. I would expect the result to be large.

Comment: Qt+matplotlib+numpy+scipy... They are probably the biggest packages you can import in a Python program, I'm not *that* surprised that the executable comes out big.

Comment: Everything you `import` is stuffed into the executable, so the larger the imported packages, the more the size of your resulting program.

Comment: QT is by far the lions share of that im sure

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I wouldn't be so sure, most PyQt applications we release with PyInstaller (generally including QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets) are under 30 MBs.

Comment: Try building with the --onedir option and see which packages are bundled with your .exe. This will tell you which are the biggest ones and you might identify some that you can exclude from the build.

Comment: Did you check that all dlls imported by pysinstaller in case of `pyinstaller --windowed montecarlo.py` are required? Pyinstaller imports too much libs sometimes.

Comment: My program imports only pandas and it is around 326 MB!

Answer (score 3):

This is normal, as the packages you import have some large transitive dependencies.

To quantify each package's contribution, simply comment out all the imports, run pyinstaller, then add them back one by one, noting the size of pyinstaller's output after each one. You probably won't find an action item in the stats, though, since your app needs each of those imports anyway.